# Swift Delegation

Tags: swift, class, share, delegation

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around delegation in Swift. After reading some guides, I was able to set it up delegation between two ViewControllers, but I'm not understanding how it works. In my first view controller, I have a a label that displays what has been entered in the second view controller which contains a text field and a button (that returns to the first view controller). Here is the code for the first view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!
func userDidEnterInformation(info: String) {
    labelText.text = info;
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "transition"){
        let secondVC: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController;
        secondVC.delegate = self;

    }    
}
```

Here's the code for the second view controller:

```
protocol DataEnteredDelegate{
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String);
}

@IBOutlet weak var userText: UITextField!
var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = nil;


@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let information = userText.text!;
    delegate!.userDidEnterInformation(information);
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true);


}
```

My understanding is that in the text inside the text field gets stored in the information constant, then the userDidEnterInformation method from the protocol is called, with the method being defined inside the first view controller. This method then changes the label inside the first view controller. The thing is, I'm not sure what is happening in the prepareForSegue function. Specifically, I'm not sure what's the purpose of secondVC.delegate = self.

I would appreciate any sort of clarity on delegation.

Comment: BTW, in Swift you can omit semicolons at the end of each line. This way your code will look less cluttered. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The protocol you created in second viewcontroller is an Interface. You must implement your first view controller with the DataEnteredDelegate protocol.

```
class FirstViewController:UIViewController, DataEnteredDelegate{
   func userDidEnterInformation(info: String) {
     //stub
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the delegate of the second VC is not set in `prepareForSegue()` it remains `nil`. The second VC is then unable to call the first VC.

On a side note, if the delegate is `nil` your code will crash because `delegate!` is trying to unwrap an optional binding with the value of `nil`. It's better to first unwrap the delegate variable:

```
if let handler = delegate {
    handler.userDidEnterInformation(information)
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [Swift's Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html), calling `userDidEnterInformation` only if `delegate` is not `nil`.

```
delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(information);
```

In addition it is recommended to declare the delegate `weak`, to prevent retain cycles:

```
weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate?
```

Answer (score 0):

The diagram is simple but can help you understand what's going on.

[image: diagram]

`FirstViewController` must conform to the `DataEnteredDelegate` protocol you have defined (see Sumit's answer). When using `secondVC.delegate = self`, you are saying that for the segue `transition` with the destination being a `SecondViewController`, the attribute `delegate` of that `SecondViewController` instance will be set to this instance of `FirstViewController`, thus delegating things from `SecondViewController` to your `FirstViewController` as made possible by the `DataEnteredDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates and Protocols

Do not try to figure out how the dictionary definition of “delegate” fits with the concept of delegation in Swift. It doesn't.

Delegation in Swift is an agreement between two players—a sensing object and a requesting object. The “delegate” is the “requesting object.” Just think “asker” or “requester” every time you see “delegate” and it will make a lot more sense. Here is their agreement...

The Sensing Object (Second View Controller):

I have data from some event that took place. I will publish instructions (a protocol) on how you may access that data. If you want it, you must do three things.

1. You must declare in your class type that your class abides by my protocol.
2. You must write the functions that I describe in my protocol. I don't care what those functions do but the function type must match what I publish.
3. In YOUR code, you must set MY “delegate” (think “asker”) property to point to you. {secondVC.delegate = self} That way I can call one of YOUR functions to deliver the data.

After that, when I get some data, I will call one of the functions in your object that I told you to write. My call to your function will contain the data you are looking for as one of the arguments. {delegate!.userDidEnterInformation(information)} Note: delegate! (asker!) is YOU.

The Delegate (Requesting) Object (First View Controller):

O.K. You've got a deal.